# fault with me vs. fault of me

Tags: prepositional-phrases

"fault **with** me" or "fault **of** me" – which is correct in the given below sentences?  I want to know which preposition, I have should use.

> 1) I always forget your book to bring. This is the fault with me.
>   2) I always forget your book to bring. This is the fault of me.

Answer (score 1):

The way we usually say this is:

> This is my fault.

Also, in your sentences, you should rephrase the first part. Instead of:

> I always forget your book to bring...

use:

> I always forget to bring your book. This is my fault.

Even in English, sometimes people use the Latin phrase *mea culpa* to indicate fault. It's usually regarded as a way to express sheepish embarrassment:

> I always forget to bring your book. *Mea culpa*.

Also, there are other, more informal ways to indicate fault in everyday conversation. I like this one:

> I always forget to bring your book. My bad.